# Как использовать gnu ассемблер на Mac Os?

Tags: ассемблер, gcc, homebrew, gnu-assembler

Установил gcc и binutils через homebrew. Далее в терминале:

```
gcc -c file.S
ld -o file.bin /lib/crt0.o file.o -lc
```

На второй строке произошла ошибка, хотя именно такая команда была в [документации](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/ld-2.9.1/html_node/ld_3.html#SEC3). Ошибка в том, что файл /lib/crt0.o не найден. Как правильно установить все инструменты gnu ассемблера?

Comment: crt*.o (на линуксах, по крайней мере), относятся не к gcc и не к binutils, а к libc-dev. На маках, возможно, к какой-то другой сущности. Кроме того, он может быть не crt0.o, а crt1.o https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E88353_01/html/E37853/crt1.o-7.html

Comment: И находиться может совсем не в /lib